# Transcendence degree of quotient field of polynomial ring over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $k$. How do you determine the transcendence degree of the quotient field $K(A) $ of $A$ over $k$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Usually by finding a transcendence basis, which should not be very hard in this case.

Comment: $K(A) $ is the field of rational functions, right? Since transcendence degree is defined when dealing with field extensions, is it here meant the dimension of $K(A)/k$?

Comment: The transcendence degree of this extension is by definition the cardinality of a transcendence basis of $K(A)/k$. So your task is to find such a basis. Note that this is not the same as a vector space basis.

Comment: Many thanks. So, an element of such an extension is a rational function with no constant term, which is to say that the extension K(A)/k is the ideal $ ((x_1)^{k_1},...(x_n)^{k_n}), k_i\in Z$ generated by the monomials $(x_i)^{k_i}$ which form the transcendence basis. Thus the transcendence degree is n. Do you agree ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ideal in this context. $K(A)$ is generated as a field over $k$ by the indeterminates $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of the polynomial ring $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and these are algebraically independent by definition, hence form a transcendence basis of $K(A)$ over $k$.

Comment: Note that in order to show that these elements indeed generate $K(A)$ as a field, it suffices to show that they generate the polynomial ring $A$ as an algebra over $k$ (this follows from the universal property of the field of fractions).

Comment: Many thanks indeed. When it is about the transcendence degree of the quotient field $K(A)$ of $A$ over $k$, is it meant the transcendence degree of $K(A) $ or of $K(A)/k$? I am confused.

Comment: Transcendence degree is always understood with respect to a field extension, you should have a look at the definition again (see my previous comment).

Comment: You wrote once in your post 'transcendence basis of $K(A)/k$' and then 'transcendence basis of $K(A) $ over $k$'. Do the two expressions mean the same? For one thing, $K(A)/k$ and $K(A) $ are not identical. Can you comment on that?

Comment: They mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing in order to avoid my confusion, when one writes $K(A)/k$, is it meant the quotient $K(A) $ modulo $k$ and thus rational fractions with no constant term (in the similar way as we encounter it when dealing with the quotient of polynomial ring by an ideal) or rather something else?

Comment: No it just means that $K(A)$ is a field extension of $k$.